# How to use literal backslash in SQL query statement?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013, backslash

EDIT2: Sorry everyone, problem solved. I WAS trying to concatenate a number with my string. I forgot that I simplified my statement when I posted here, thinking my problem had to do with the backslash rather than type compatibility. You guys are right and I was being an idiot. Thanks!

I'm using `Access 2013` where my query pulls its data from a SQL 10.0 server (using pass-through).

I am trying to use the backslash in my SQL query like below (***edit: tbltask.jobnum is a string in my database):

```
SELECT [tblEstimator].[Name] + '\\20' + [tbltask].[JobNum] + ' JOBS\\' AS JobMidFilePath
```

But when I run the query, I get the error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '\\20' to data type smallint. (#245)

I have no idea what this means or why it's trying to convert anything to smallint.

Comment: [tbltask].[JobNum]  is this a small int? It might be trying to cast it

Comment: Nope, tbltaskJobNum is a string. But it is composed of just numbers.

Comment: @Mike You cannot concatenate numbers with strings directly. You would need to cast them as a string to do that.

Comment: But I do not have numbers in my concatenation. Estimator name is a string, '\20' is a string, JobNum is a string (composed of numbers, but it's still a string), etc. Or are you saying that if a string is composed of numbers SQL automatically casts it as an integer so I have to convert it back into a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replicate your issue, we can write a query something like this:

```
declare @name varchar(50) = 'Test',
        @JobNum smallint = 12

select @name + '\\20' + @JobNum + ' JOBS\\';
```

This will return the same error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Test\20' to data
>   type smallint.

But if you convert the `smallint` or the number field to a string like this, the error should go away:

```
declare @name varchar(50) = 'Test',
        @JobNum smallint = 12

select @name + '\\20' + cast(@JobNum as varchar(10)) + ' JOBS\\'
```

Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT [tblEstimator].[Name] + '\\20' + cast([tbltask].[JobNum] as varchar(10)) 
       + ' JOBS\\' AS JobMidFilePath
```

I am not sure the equivalent of `MS-ACESS` on this, but that should resolve your issue.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I forgot to mention that tbltask.JobNum is a string in my database. I tried converting it to a string using the method you described just in case, but I am still getting the exact same error

Comment: Hmm...you said you are pulling your data from SQL Server database? Is it possible to post your table structure?

Comment: Yes and I made an "edit2" in my post. you and everyone else were right that I was trying to concatenate a number with strings.

Comment: @Mike No worries! Please close this question by choosing the best answer that fits your needs and helped you most. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

First off, you can try to cast/convert your int as your output should be string. If the single quote doesn't work, you can try using double qoute (")

```
SELECT [tblEstimator].[Name] + "\\20" + CAST([tbltask].[JobNum] as varchar(100)) + " JOBS\\" AS JobMidFilePath
```

Comment: This has syntax issues.

Comment: I added the missing close parenthesis ')' in the cast. This should work now.

Comment: You cannot use double quotes as well.

Comment: You can try using single quotes if double quotes doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*You can copy/paste directly into SQL, comments will be commented out ini SQL syntax
I would create a temp table to achieve this. */

USE whateverDB
GO

CREATE TABLE #toSelectFrom (
    Name VARCHAR (100) 
    ,JobNum TINYINT
    /*look at the schema, it'll tell you what the data type is in SQL tables, in the column folder [see image] (http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MKPtdjq3MzA/maxresdefault.jpg) - copy verbatim to your temp table columns */
    ,slashPathNumber VARCHAR (25)
    ,slashPathJobs VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT INTO #toSelectFrom (Name, slashPathNumber, JobNum, slashPathJobs)
SELECT [tblEstimator].[Name], '\\\\20', [tbltask].[JobNum], ' JOBS\\' AS JobMidFilePath /*** FROM yourTableToSelectFrom -- you NEED THIS FOR VALID SQL! ***/ 

--Then just: 
SELECT * FROM #toSelectFrom;
-- OR Alternatively:
SELECT Name + slashPathNumber + JobNum + slashPathJobs AS JobMidFilePath FROM #toSelectFrom;

/*
If you use it a lot, just write the above select statement(s) into a view to select from more often. ;)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks Futbol, still new to Stack tons to share and really enjoying helping out but taking a bit of getting used to the answer syntax editor.